# google maps autocomplete not working How can I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

js loading:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC3Ws7EvlZS2PRlNFZfFrqOnlWM_XHYO1o&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox controls" placeholder="Post Code,City" id="cityzip" name="cityzip" value="">
```

JS Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function(){
          var autocomplete;
          var geocoder;
          var input = document.getElementById('cityzip');
          var options = {
            types: ['(regions)'] // (cities)
          };

          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

JS Code placed before closing body tag. I placed Gmaps file loading before closing head. I don't know why it's not working can anyone please help me.

Comment: Hmm... seems like ok for me: http://jsbin.com/tuzujiwera/edit?html,js,console,output Problem is in another place

Comment: so why not working on my website http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing

Comment: It works on your page also.

Answer (score 2):

I created a fiddle and its working fine

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function(){
          var autocomplete;
          var geocoder;
          var input = document.getElementById('cityzip');
          var options = {
            types: ['(regions)'] // (cities)
          };

          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC3Ws7EvlZS2PRlNFZfFrqOnlWM_XHYO1o&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" class="textbox controls" placeholder="Post Code,City" id="cityzip" name="cityzip" value="">
```